# Javascript code is not working defined in php variable

Tags: javascript, php

i am very new to java script.I tried to call a javascript code which was defined in a php variable.But its not actually doing what my javascript code has to do when i echo that particular php variable.
Here is my code

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['subscribe_email']) && $_SESSION['subscribe_email']!=""){
    logw("inside_if".$_SESSION['subscribe_email']);
if ($_SESSION['subscribe_email'] === 'SUCCESS') {
    $subscribe_session_value = "<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('#id_subscribe_button').text('Successfully Subscribed');

            $('#exampleInputEmail2').hide();
            alert('success');
            </script>

";

    echo $subscribe_session_value;
} else if ($_SESSION['subscribe_email'] === 'ALREADY_EXISTING') {
    $subscribe_session_value = "<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('#id_subscribe_button').text('Already Subscribed');

            $('#exampleInputEmail2').hide();
             alert('Already Subscribed');
            </script>

";

     echo $subscribe_session_value;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it gets through the good condition?
Try showing page source to see if your js code is included.

Comment: @Loïc thanks man I saw page source and  found that I forget to add "});" at the end of that php variable.Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `$(document).ready` function is not close properly means missing `});` try this

```
if ($_SESSION['subscribe_email'] === 'SUCCESS') {
    $subscribe_session_value = "<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                            $('#id_subscribe_button').text('Successfully Subscribed');

                                            $('#exampleInputEmail2').hide();
                                            alert('success');
                                        }); 
                                </script>
";

    echo $subscribe_session_value;
} else if ($_SESSION['subscribe_email'] === 'ALREADY_EXISTING') {
    $subscribe_session_value = "<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                            $('#id_subscribe_button').text('Already Subscribed');

                                            $('#exampleInputEmail2').hide();
                                            alert('Already Subscribed');
                                        });
                                </script>

";

     echo $subscribe_session_value;
}
```